# How can I verify if a datetime object in php is different than 0?

Tags: php

In my php code I have a variable:

```
$mytime = 0;
```

later on in code when I'm going through several if statements, at some point I'm adding to this variable a new datetime object:

```
$mytime = new DateTime($input);
```

however, this situation varies - sometimes I'm adding this value and sometimes I'm not touching this variable at all. And then in my code I have an if statement:

```
if($mytime != 0)
```

and when this variable has a datetime type, I'm getting an error:

```
Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string
```

How can I change - either my declaration of `$mytime` or the if statement - so that everything works fine here?
Thanks!

Comment: You can't if zero is the actual value you pass to DateTime. It is not a valid value and will throw an error. You need to change your code and add validation around the value of `$input`.

Comment: Thanks, but the situation happens even if I do this `$mytime = new DateTime();` My problem is that I have a variable $mytime and later on with my logic I can check if it's different than 0. But when I assign datetime value to this variable and try to check if it's different than 0, then I'm getting this error...

Comment: Did you try my method yet?

Comment: I tried, but I still have some problems with it. It might work when 0 is assigned to it, but when I assign any datetime object to it, then I have the error mentioned in my original post. That is because it's impossible to compare the datetime object to 0, but I don't know how to fix it yet...

Comment: That shouldn't have happened with my method. If you serialize the object, it turns it into a string, so you shouldn't be comparing the datetime object to 0. You would be comparing the string to 0.

Comment: Can you show the code using my method, so I can test it?

Answer (score -1):

DateTime is an object. To check for errors after parsing the date ($input) you should use a try / catch statement

```
try {
    $mytime = new DateTime($input);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // ERRORS HERE
    print_r(DateTime::getLastErrors());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can `serialize($mytime)` to convert the object to a string first, before comparing. So, something like this in your if statement would work:

```
if (serialize($mytime) != 0)
```